# Random primes and Rabin Karp substring search

Tags: string, algorithm, random, primes, rabin-karp

I am reading the Rabin-Karb algorithm from Sedgewick. The book says:

> We use a random prime Q taking as large a value as possible while
> avoiding overflow

At first reading I didn't notice the significance of *random* and when I saw that in the code a `long` is used my first thoughts were:
a) Use Eratosthene's sieve to find a big prime that fits a `long`
or
b) look up from a list of primes any prime large enough that is greater than `int` and use it as a constant.

But then the rest of the explanation says:

> We will use a `long` value greater than `10^20` making the probability
> that a collision happens less than `10^-20`

This part got me confused since a `long` can not fit `10^20` let alone a value greater than that.
Then when I checked the calculation for the prime the book defers to an exercise that has just the following hint:

> A random n-digit number is prime with probability proportional to 1/n

What does that mean?

So basically what I don't get is:
a) what is the meaning of using a *random* prime? Why can't we just pre-calculate it and use it as a constant?
b) why is the `10^20` mentioned since it is out of range for `long`?
c) How is that hint helpful? What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Does the exercise also ask for an effort estimation?

Comment: @Henry: The solution of the exercise actually is provided here https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/RabinKarp.java.html and does not seem to be aligned with the description of the text as it uses `BigInteger.probablePrime(31, new Random());` I.e. 32 bits and dont get how it is linked with the rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383650/are-there-multiple-kmp-algorithmic-approaches-with-different-space-complexities), Sedgewick has tried to simplify an algorithm and gotten the details slightly wrong. First, as you observe, 10<sup>20</sup> cannot be represented in 64 bits. Even taking a prime close to 2<sup>63</sup> − 1, however, you probably would want a bit of room to multiply the normal way without overflowing so that the subsequent modulo is correct. The answer uses a 31-bit prime, which makes this easy but only offers collision probabilities in the 10<sup>−9</sup> range.

The original version uses [Rabin fingerprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) and a random [irreducible polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) over <sub>2</sub>[x], which from the perspective of algebraic number theory behaves a lot like a random prime over the integers. If we choose the polynomial to be degree 32 or 64, then the fingerprints fit perfectly into a computer word of the appropriate length, and polynomial addition and subtraction both work out to bitwise XOR, so there is no overflow.

Now, Sedgewick presumably didn't want to explain how polynomial rings work. Fine. If I had to implement this approach in practice, I'd choose a prime p close to the max *that was easy to mod by with cheap instructions* (I'm partial to <strike>2<sup>31</sup> − 2<sup>27</sup> + 1</strike>; EDIT actually 2<sup>31</sup> − 1 works even better since we don't need a smooth prime here) and then choose a random number in [1, p−1] to evaluate the polynomials at (this is how Wikipedia explains it). The reason that we need some randomness is that otherwise the oblivious adversary could choose an input that would be guaranteed to have a lot of hash collisions, which would severely degrade the running time.

Sedgewick wanted to follow the original a little more closely than that, however, which in essence evaluates the polynomials at a fixed value of x (literally x in the original version that uses polynomial rings). He needs a random prime so that the oblivious adversary can't engineer collisions. Sieving numbers big enough is quite inefficient, so he turns to the Prime Number Theorem (which is the math behind his hint, but it holds only asymptotically, which makes a big mess theoretically) and a fast primality test (which can be probabilistic; the  cases where it fails won't influence the correctness of the algorithm, and they are rare enough that they won't affect the expected running time).

I'm not sure how he proves a formal bound on the collision probability. My rough idea is basically, show that there are enough primes in the window of interest, use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to show that it's impossible for there to be a collision for too many primes at once, conclude that the collision probability is bounded by the probability of picking a bad prime, which is low. But the Prime Number Theorem holds only asymptotically, so we have to rely on computer experiments regarding the density of primes in machine word ranges. Not great.

Comment: In the code `Q` is used only in `%` and division. Specifically `txtHash = (txtHash + Q - RM*txt.charAt(i-m) % Q) % Q; ` and `xtHash = (txtHash*R + txt.charAt(i)) % Q;` So although M <<< Q the overflow is still possible?

Comment: `I'm not sure how he proves a formal bound on the collision probability.` The book just says that by using a `long` value greater than `10^20` it makes the probability that a random key hashes to the same value as the pattern less than `10^-20` and leaves it at that. Then in the proposition that the search is linear-time and extremely likely to be correct the book says that `the use of the very large value of Q makes it extremely unlikely that a collision will occur..Robin and Karp showed that when Q is properly chosen we get a hash collision for random string with probability 1/Q`

Comment: I don't know how I could have derived the Prime Number theorem or polynomial rings etc to be honest from the text

Comment: I hadn't consider the case of a malicious input. That explains why a constant prime should be avoided yeah. Thank you for explaining that

Comment: @Jim you don't have to go all the way down to Q ~ 2^31, but it can't be very close to the word limit without a custom multiplication operator.

Comment: `a prime p close to the max that was easy to mod by with cheap instructions ` what is max here? max 64 bit value? Also what do you mean by cheap instructions? Is that language/platform dependent on how the `mod` is done? I know for power of 2 we can just do bitwise operations for modulo so I assume that is faster than `%` e.g in Java?

Comment: @Jim Multiply two 32-bit values as 64-bit quantities, then reduce. A good compiler will be able to strength reduce the modulo operation as is (or you can do it yourself with a couple of shifts and subtractions).

Comment: `The answer uses a 31-bit prime, which makes this easy but only offers collision probabilities in the 10^−9 range.` does that necessitate the modification of the algorithm to `Las Vegas` approach as it is called in the book? I.e. after hash match compare against the substring?

Comment: @Jim Depends on whether you want to fail wrong or slow. Or you could implement 64-bit Rabin fingerprints and roll the dice.

Comment: So is the algorithm a theoritical approach? Googling, the Rabin Karp examples that come up for Java are basically checking the chars of the pattern against the text if there is a hash match. Which makes the worse case the same as brute force. Or is the exact implementation actually possible?

Comment: @Jim The worst case is very unlikely given an adversary that's actually oblivious (questionable assumption for some applications) and a random source that's working properly.

Comment: So is `BigInteger.probablePrime(31, new Random());` reasonable then (with the extra check on hash match) for production code in general?

Comment: @Jim Yeah, I think so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clarifications! Much appreciated!!!!